Error while pushing artifacts to Gitlab Package registry
I am trying to push artifacts to gitlab package registry using gradle but getting error Could not find property 'HttpHeaderCredentials' on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.DefaultMavenArtifactRepository_Decorated@641e902.
I am following the official documentation but no luck. I have added the below configuration.

Under build.gradle
  publishing {
 publications {
     library(MavenPublication) {
         from components.java
     }
 }
 repositories {
     maven {
         url "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/<PROJECT_ID>/packages/maven"
         credentials(HttpHeaderCredentials) {
             name = "Job-Token"
             value = gitLabPrivateToken // the variable resides in $GRADLE_USER_HOME/gradle.properties
         }
         authentication {
             header(HttpHeaderAuthentication)
         }
     }
 }

}


and
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'maven-publish'
}


Under gradle.properties

gitLabPrivateToken=System.getenv("CI_JOB_TOKEN")

Under .gitlab-ci.yml

.gitlab-ci.yml
But getting error:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'kml-builder-service'.

Could not find property 'HttpHeaderCredentials' on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.DefaultMavenArtifactRepository_Decorated@641e902.

